# Where is my Rock-It Launcher?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

One of the greatest build-it-yourself items in Fallout 3 was the Rock-It Launcher. I swear, I found the schematics for it like 3 or 4 times.

However, I've made it all the way through New Vegas twice now, and can't seem to find it. Where can I find it? Or, did they get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was cut before launch. I *believe* it's floating around in the game files, and if so, it should be fairly trivial to mod in if you're playing on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I found the schematics in the Mess Hall on Nellis AFB.  I have yet to find a Leaf Blower, however.  When I use a workbench, it does not appear on the list of things I can craft, though I don't know if that's right.  I am on my first play though, lousy repair skill and I've never played fallout before.  I can see the recipe in my pip-boy.

Comment: According to the Fallout Wikia, the schematics are non-functional as you discovered.

Comment: You'd need to find one of the mods to do it, or make the mod yourself.